# Kinesis Firehose with Lambda decorator getting throttled

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am using Firehose with a lambda decorator to ingest vpc flow logs into Redshift.
(VPC Flow Logs -> Kinesis Data Stream -> Kinesis Firehose -> Lambda Decorator -> Redshift) The volume of traffic is high which causes the lambda to error out with task timed out when reingesting unprocessed records back into firehose. The lambda has the max timeout and 3GB of memory.

I believe the issue is related to lambda's 6mb payload size. Is there a way to batch or reduce the payload to ensure the function doesn't error out? Thanks in advance.

```
    import base64
    import json
    import gzip
    import StringIO
    import boto3
    import datetime

    def transformLogEvent(log_event):
        version     = log_event['extractedFields']['version']
        accountid   = log_event['extractedFields']['account_id']
        interfaceid = log_event['extractedFields']['interface_id']
        srcaddr     = log_event['extractedFields']['srcaddr']
        dstaddr     = log_event['extractedFields']['dstaddr']
        srcport     = log_event['extractedFields']['srcport']
        dstport     = log_event['extractedFields']['dstport']
        protocol    = log_event['extractedFields']['protocol']
        packets     = log_event['extractedFields']['packets']
        bytes       = log_event['extractedFields']['bytes']
        starttime   = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(log_event['extractedFields']['start'])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        endtime     = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(log_event['extractedFields']['end'])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        action      = log_event['extractedFields']['action']
        logstatus   = log_event['extractedFields']['log_status']

        row = '"' + str(version) + '"' + "," + '"' + str(accountid) + '"' + "," + '"' + str(interfaceid) + '"' + "," + '"' + str(srcaddr) + '"' + "," + '"' + str(dstaddr) + '"' + "," + '"' + str(srcport) + '"' + "," + '"' + str(dstport) + '"' + "," + '"' + str(protocol) + '"' + "," + '"' + str(packets) + '"' + "," + '"' + str(bytes) + '"' + "," + '"' + str(starttime) + '"' + "," + '"' + str(endtime) + '"' + "," + '"' + str(action) + '"' + "," + '"' + str(logstatus) + '"' + "\n"
        #print(row)
        return row

    def processRecords(records):
        for r in records:
            data = base64.b64decode(r['data'])
            striodata = StringIO.StringIO(data)
            try:
                with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=striodata, mode='r') as f:
                    data = json.loads(f.read())
            except IOError:
                # likely the data was re-ingested into firehose
                pass

            recId = r['recordId']
            # re-ingested data into firehose
            if type(data) == str:
                yield {
                    'data': data,
                    'result': 'Ok',
                    'recordId': recId
                }
            elif data['messageType'] != 'DATA_MESSAGE':
                yield {
                    'result': 'ProcessingFailed',
                    'recordId': recId
                }
            else:
                data = ''.join([transformLogEvent(e) for e in data['logEvents']])
                #print(data)
                data = base64.b64encode(data)
                yield {
                    'data': data,
                    'result': 'Ok',
                    'recordId': recId
                }


    def putRecords(streamName, records, client, attemptsMade, maxAttempts):
        failedRecords = []
        codes = []
        errMsg = ''
        try:
            response = client.put_record_batch(DeliveryStreamName=streamName, Records=records)
        except Exception as e:
            failedRecords = records
            errMsg = str(e)

        # if there are no failedRecords (put_record_batch succeeded), iterate over the response to gather results
        if not failedRecords and response['FailedPutCount'] > 0:
            for idx, res in enumerate(response['RequestResponses']):
                if not res['ErrorCode']:
                    continue

                codes.append(res['ErrorCode'])
                failedRecords.append(records[idx])

            errMsg = 'Individual error codes: ' + ','.join(codes)

        if len(failedRecords) > 0:
            if attemptsMade + 1 < maxAttempts:
                print('Some records failed while calling PutRecords, retrying. %s' % (errMsg))
                putRecords(streamName, failedRecords, client, attemptsMade + 1, maxAttempts)
            else:
                raise RuntimeError('Could not put records after %s attempts. %s' % (str(maxAttempts), errMsg))


    def handler(event, context):
        streamARN = ''
        region = ''
        streamName = ''

        records = list(processRecords(event['records']))
        projectedSize = 0
        recordsToReingest = []
        for idx, rec in enumerate(records):
            if rec['result'] == 'ProcessingFailed':
                continue
            projectedSize += len(rec['data']) + len(rec['recordId'])
            # 4000000 instead of 6291456 to leave ample headroom for the stuff we didn't account for
            if projectedSize > 4000000:
                recordsToReingest.append({
                    'Data': rec['data']
                })
                records[idx]['result'] = 'Dropped'
                del(records[idx]['data'])

        if len(recordsToReingest) > 0:
            client = boto3.client('firehose', region_name=region)
            putRecords(streamName, recordsToReingest, client, attemptsMade=0, maxAttempts=20)
            print('Reingested %d records out of %d' % (len(recordsToReingest), len(event['records'])))
        else:
            print('No records to be reingested')

        return {"records": records}
```